# NSData contains : <null> initWithData:jsonData crash

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking

How to avoid the crash ?

```
NSData contains : <null> 
"NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  // Crash
```

Comment: can you post your crash log here ?

Comment: How are you getting `jsonData`? Whatever is passed in is not necessarily valid UTF-8 data...

Comment: Sorry, there is no timely response, before too busy. Now has to solve this problem, is a small problem.